# Tkinter label isn't being destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I wrote a little questionnaire and the questions won't be destroyed by clicking on the next or check button. Sometimes it works and sometimes not. It's really strange. The questions will be put on top of the old one. It's like a pile of questions and that's really annoying.

> ```
> def myLabeldestroy(self):
>     myLabel01.destroy()
> def checkAnswer(self):
>     ###Creation of random integers
>     self.iniRand()
>     ###Delete myLabel
>     self.myLabeldestroy()
>     self.mylabel(self.theories[self.qList][self.index][self.zero], 0, 1)
>     ###Check whether answer is in used list or not
>     if self.theories[self.qList] not in self.usedTheories:
>         if self.gs[self.index][self.zero] not in self.used:
>             ###Correct answer  
>             self.myEntry.get() == str(self.theories[self.qList][self.index][self.one])
>             self.used.append(self.gs[self.index][self.zero])
>             self.mylabel(self.answer[self.answerIndex], 2, 1)
>             self.counter += self.one
>             ###Point counter
>             self.mylabel("Point counter " + str(self.counter), 4, 1)
>         ###Wrong answer
>         else:
>             self.mylabel(self.reply[self.answerIndex], 2, 1)
> def nextAnswer(self):
>     ###Creation of random integers
>     self.iniRand()
>     ###Delete myLabel
>     self.myLabeldestroy()
>     self.mylabel(self.theories[self.qList][self.index][self.zero], 0, 1)
>     ###Check whether answer is in used list or not
>     if self.theories[self.qList] not in self.usedTheories:
>         if self.gs[self.index][self.zero] not in self.used:
>             self.used.append(self.gs[self.index][self.zero])
>             self.counter -= self.one
>             ###Point counter
>             self.mylabel("Point counter " + str(self.counter), 4, 1)
> ```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: Have you verified that your function is being called? Are you certain it's not throwing an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out my mistake. I had to create two destroy methods.

> ```
> def myLabeldestroyStart(self):
>     self.myLabelstart01.destroy()
> def myLabeldestroyQuestions(self):
>     self.myLabelquestion01.destroy()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I can advise you to use another method.If you are .pack() method, use pack_forget() or grid_forget() if you are using .grid().Learn more about it from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-forget_pack-and-forget_grid-method-in-tkinter/).

Comment: That doesn't make a difference whether destroying or forgetting and object. Forget method just makes it invisible.